# Is it possible to dock multiple ligands with the target?

Tags: bioinformatics

Is it possible to dock multiple ligands with a target? If so, what is the suitable software used for? -- Is it possible to fix specific docking region for the target (or) automatic?

Answer (score 3):

Huameng Li and Chenglong Li have done multiple ligand docking in two (AFAIK) of their works:

1. [Multiple ligand simultaneous docking: Orchestrated dancing of ligands in binding sites of protein](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jcc.21486/full)
2. [Drug Design Targeting Protein–Protein Interactions (PPIs) Using Multiple Ligand Simultaneous Docking (MLSD).....](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jm401144z)

The method is called Multiple Ligand Simultaneous Docking (MLSD). I am not at all an expert in this field and you should read the first paper for details on how they implemented this. This algorithm was implemented on AutoDock.

Comment: I thank and appreciate [WYSIWYG] for your wonderful answer. I have referred the both articles before, but there is no proper protocol for applying the problem in the AutoDock.

Comment: Perhaps you can see [this](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/%28SICI%291096-987X%2819981115%2919:14%3C1639::AID-JCC10%3E3.0.CO;2-B/abstract) paper. They talk about implementing automated docking and this is referred by Li and Li.